# Is it possible to post promotional activities to the social media accounts of users who have logged in via Firebase Social media authentication?

Tags: firebase-authentication, ads, facebook-authentication

I have implemented the social media sign up/Log in via firebase authentication . I get the User UID from the Firebase-SDK when a user is authenticated . Can this ID be used for targeted ad campaign to those particular users ? If it's not feasible then how I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication asks for the minimal set of scopes that it needs to sign the user in (read-access to name, email, profile picture URL). This does not allow your code to make any posts on the user's behalf.

On adding more scopes, see:

- [How to add scopes to Facebook login with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218093/how-to-add-scopes-to-facebook-login-with-firebase)
- [firebase Facebook oAuth addScope()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177529/firebase-facebook-oauth-addscope)